# i want to make condition statement but unsuccessful

Tags: sql, vb.net

hi i want to make condition statement in my function. i use this method :

```
If String.ReferenceEquals(hotel, hotel) = true Then

        insertDatabase()
    Else
        updateDatabase()

    End If
```

if i try to insert a data already in the database, the function will directly go to the updateDatabase()..

the problem is, if i try to insert the data that currently not in the database, the function will directly go to update database as well..

maybe the method i use is not suitable. can anyone help?..im using vb.net and sql..

Comment: In your sample code, you are comparing the same values (hotel)

Answer (score 1):

Some issues:

`String.ReferenceEquals` will only return true for the same string object, not the same string value - not a good idea. The `=` operator is suitable overridden in the `String` class to allow you to just use that.

There's no point adding an `= true` for a Boolean function.

So change your first line to something like:

```
If hotel1 = hotel2 Then
```